# Need help with figuring out variables for t-test for dependen samples

Tags: paired-data

I am trying to figure out t test for dependent samples and need help.
Let's say that our research question is "is there a difference between length of essay and narration text in children with developmental language disorder", in class we learned that our dependent variable would be "length of essay and narration text". It seems like two separate things, but i googled a bit and figured out it's because they both are trying to figure out productivity of a text, right? And our independent variable is language status. And if there is a statistic difference, interpretation and descriptive statistics would be sth like "there is a difference in length of essay and narration text in children with DLD.  children with DLD are writing longer essay than narration text (just an example, of course depends on results)." What confuses me is it seems like there are two dependent variables that we are comparing, even though our professor said that there is only one. So i don't really understand the interpretation, i don't understand why we put two dependent variables in SPSS if there is only one. I'm so confused. I get that we are measuring the same group at two different things, but I don't get the dependent variable.
Also in a research question "Is there a difference between length of essay and comprehension of s text in children with DLD", what would be dependent and independent variables here? I'm so confused about this.
I really appreciate anyone who answers and helps me out, so sorry for bad English, it's not my first language.